# First Posts review didn't register after using last vote

Tags: bug, review, voting

I've reviewed a post in the First Posts queue, which included my last vote for the day. After clicking on <kbd>I'm Done</kbd>, I received the "vote limit reached" message on the same screen.  After checking back my reviews again, it appears that it wasn't counted.

This occurred on Code Review, a site on which I have a diamond, so I was able to check the post timeline, which *did* show that I reviewed that post.  This makes me even more confused...

Is this a bug or (somehow) by-design?

Comment: Sounds like a buggy edge case.